# Meaning of Mishlei 14:18?

Tags: commentaries, mishlei

Shalom.

Mishlei 14:18 reads, in Rabbi Eliezer Ginsburg’s English translation, ‘Simpletons have inherited folly, but the shrewd make knowledge a crown.’

I only have Rabbi Ginsburg’s commentary on this verse (Artscroll Mishlei commentary, 2022 CE). The commentary on the first part of the verse reads:

‘Foolishness is their inheritance (Ibn Ezra), because they accept the words of fools and skeptics indiscriminately, as an heir would accept an inheritance (Malbim). […] They hold on to their foolishness like a person holds on to an inheritance (Metzudos).’

I am not happy with this commentary because it implies, to me, that simpletons (peti’im) are foolish. Hashem condemns fools, but we all know that simpletons are protected by Him (Tehillim 116:6).

To me, this verse means: Simpletons are placed in the path of fools by Hashem, and are exposed to their foolishness, as punishment for their simplicity, but clever men are relieved of such exposure and live like princes among the wise.

Does anyone have a good commentary that is kinder to simpletons than Rabbi Ginsburg’s reading, and argues along the lines that I have presented above?

Many thanks for your time.

P.S. I intend to contact Rabbi Ginsburg about this, but would prefer to give him some sources, rather than simply give my own opinion.

Comment: We are in the same sugya it seems at the moment. Slightly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139744/what-does-torah-say-about-how-innate-our-intelligence-is

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii - forgive me, I posted a comment just now that could be read as minut - I meant to say that I came at this question through a simple meditation on Tehillim 116:6, Mishlei 14:18 and Rabbi Ginzberg’s commentary. No Karaitism intended. We have the same concern here - blessings to you. :)

Comment: I don't have answers, but just some suggestions in methodology that may yield some if you work on it: 1) Have you gone back to analyze the idea of Tehillim 116:6? Perhaps its scope is more narrow than you've previously conceived of and is therefore inapplicable to Mishle 14:18. 2) Is there a difference between inheriting foolishness and being foolish? It seems to me that one can easily lapse into the other, but that they are separate occasions... just some thoughts... happy learning :)

Comment: @Deuteronomy - many thanks - I will meditate on this. Blessings :) T